# How can we write Unit Test below Code?Can any one help me in this one

Tags: asp.net, mocking, asp.net-identity

```
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _signInManager = value;
        }
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
      var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync
      (model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");

            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a mocking framework like MOQ. mock up a SignInManager. Write a unit test for each case.